# Why do I need -fPIC for compiling with --unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files?

Tags: c++, linker, loading, elf

I have the following 2 files:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int f();
int main(){
  std::cout<<f();
}
```

functions.cpp:

```
int f(){
   return 42;
}
```

I compile functions.cpp into libfunctions.so using this command:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared functions.cpp -o libfunctions.so
```

I compile main.cpp into a.out using this command:

```
g++ main.cpp -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
```

When I run a.out using this command:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./libfunctions.so ./a.out
```

I get a segmentation fault.

But if I compile main.cpp into a.out using this command:

```
g++ -fPIC main.cpp -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
```

Then it works.

I understand why shared libraries have to be compiled with -fPIC, since one cannot know the address at which where they will be loaded at load time. However I do not understand why `main.cpp` must also be compiled as PIC. I thought that since the load address for `a.out` is known at link time, then surely there is no need to compile with `-fPIC`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using the GNU toolchain.  binutils ld sometimes produces corrupt binaries for invalid input, unfortunately, rather than failing with an error message.

In your case, I get:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: unexpected PLT reloc type 0x00
```

This error message is correct:

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x628 contains 4 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
…
000000000000  000000000000 R_X86_64_NONE                        0
```

`R_X86_64_NONE` has the value zero, and it is sometimes used by ld instead of a real relocation if an error is encountered.

Whether this is an ld bug, is debatable.  ld produced the binary you asked for, ignoring the error.  It did produce an invalid relocation.  When compiling with `-fno-plt`, I get no relocation at all, but the program still crashes because the resolved symbol appears to have offset 0 relative to the executable or text section.

I suspect that with `-fPIC`, it happens to work for you because ld produces a dynamic relocation for the unknown symbol.  (I cannot get binutils 2.30 to produce this relocation, though.)

In general, it is *impossible* to generate a correct dynamic relocation to an undefined symbol.  Without the definition, on many architectures, it is impossible to tell whether the target is a function or object.  Undefined references to objects need accurate size information if copy relocations are used.  Both function and object references need a symbol definition to obtain the correct symbol version (if any).  There are many reasons why underlinking is extremely problematic.

It may be worth reporting this as a binutils linker bug, but I assume it will be treated as very low priority.

Comment: Is it supposed to produce a dynamic relocation for unknown symbols?

Comment: In general, it's not possible to produce a correct dynamic relocation for an unknown symbol. Size and version information would be missing.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further? I'm not sure why it needs to know the size of a symbol when that could differ by library version.I thought that one of the main reasons to have dynamic linking is so you can have different `.so` files provide the same function with different implementations.

Comment: Object symbols have a size, and you cannot change the size without impacting ABI compatibility (even if the size is not visible at the C level). Without a definition, the link editor will not know if the symbol refers to a function or to an object.